# How can we call the spring API with multiple parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I tried several ways to call the spring API from spring controller but I could not make it. Can someone please give me some clue on how to post value to the API like this?

```
@POST
@Path("/referencesfromconverter/update/{referenceType}/{jsonOutput}")
public void saveReferences(@PathParam("referenceType") String referenceType, 
                           @PathParam("jsonOutput") String jsonOutput)
```

My code to call the API but it is not working.

```
public static void sendPostReferences(String referenceType,String jsonOutput) throws Exception
{
    List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<>();
    String       postUrl       = "http://localhost:8181/EngineServer/rest/converterbuilder/json/referencesfromconverter/update";
    HttpClient   httpClient    = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost     post          = new HttpPost(postUrl);

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(referenceType,jsonOutput));
    try{
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        String authString = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);

        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(post);
        log.info(String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
        log.info(String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hello,
Can you tell what your service should do ? Why have you jsonOutput as path param ?

Comment: Hi Oreste,
When we call the api we pass a refereceType like valueChain, coreProcess and a json object with it. The api is written by some other guy and I need to post data to the api. The path param is used as it require two parameters as far as I have understood.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Spring, I would recommend to build URL using `UriComponentsBuilder`:

```
URI postUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString("http://localhost:8181/EngineServer/rest/converterbuilder/json")
    .path("/referencesfromconverter/update/{referenceType}/{jsonOutput}")
    .buildAndExpand(referenceType, jsonOutput)
    .encode()
    .toUri();
```

And then pass it as parameter to `HttpPost` constructor.

Comment: Hi Yoory,
I tried to apply your implementation but got this error.

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.
I downloaded the spring-framework.jar file and imported it but its not working.

Comment: @Biraj , `UriComponentsBuilder` is part of [spring-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web). From tags, I thought that you use Spring on both sides, but now it seems that it is only on server side and not on client. It may be not worth importing a ton of new dependencies only to build a URL. From code example I see that you use Apache Http Client, quick googling shows that it has its own [URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html)

Comment: Don't fully understand its escaping rules, but something like this should work: `URI postUrl = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8181/")
    .setPath("/EngineServer/rest/converterbuilder/json/referencesfromconverter/update/" + referenceType + "/"  + jsonOutput)
    .build();` (but probably will break if `referenceType` or `jsonOutput` contain slashes). And I also agree with Oreste Viron that JSON should be in request body, not in URL.

Comment: Thanks  Yoory N . I will apply it and let you know.

Comment: Hi Yoory, it worked. Do you have any reference for how we can pass JSON in request body? I could easily pass one JSON value in request body but in this service I need to send two parameters which I could not. If you can help then please reply.
Thank you

Comment: From your example I see only one JSON value - `jsonOutput`. The second parameter - `referenceType` - is not a JSON (at least in your comment to Oreste's answer it was a simple string "frontBack"), you can leave it in URL path. In situations where you need to pass 2 or more JSON objects in request body, they usually wrapped in some container object like this: `{"jsonA": {<place object A here}, "jsonB": {<object B here>}, ..., "jzonZ": {<and Z here>}`. (Of course you also need to make server side to support this complex json object in request).

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. Use params.add will produce url like this :
/referencesfromconverter/update?referenceType=jsonOutput

You must concat your params with url.
Du something like this :

```
String url = "/referencesfromconverter/update/" + referenceType + "/" + jsonOutput;
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but it throws this error
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 103: http://localhost:8181/EngineServer/rest/converterbuilder/json/referencesfromconverter/update/frontBack/[{"id":null,"title":"Training","sequenceNo":0},{"id":null,"title":"External","sequenceNo":0},{"id":null,"title":"Manage","sequenceNo":0},{"id":null,"title":"Internal","sequenceNo":0}]

Comment: Due to the nature of your params, you should encode them with base64

Comment: I should mention that this is not a good practice to pass json as pathparam. It should be in the body of the request.